# HTML Pagination without reloading page

Tags: html, pagination

I'm currently working on a little project which involves a table with pictures in. Currently the table is there and I have pagination numbers on the page, but they currently don't do anything.

Here's the code I have for my table:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/750x450" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/750x450" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/750x450" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/750x450" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here's the code I have for the pagination numbers:

```
<div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the user clicks on the next page, id like another table to appear but of course separate from the table on the first page. I know I can link the pagination externally, but how do I do it internally so the page doesn't reload when the user clicks the button?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not a table at all.

Comment: Okay @mopsyd a portfolio then...